# How to correctly pick the dynamic library from the runtimes folder?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, nuget, dllimport

I am building a Nuget package that contains bindings for a dynamic library. There is a shared library (`.so`, `.dylib`, `.dll` etc) for each supported platform in the `runtimes` folder. I want the Nuget package to work on all of these platforms.

The project file has this:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="runtimes/win-x64/native/*" PackagePath="runtimes/win-x64/native/" Pack="true" />
    <None Include="runtimes/linux-x64/native/*" PackagePath="runtimes/linux-x64/native/" Pack="true" />
    <!-- etc... -->
  </ItemGroup>
```

When using `DllImport`, I can specify the path like this:

```ml
let UtilsLibPath = "runtimes/linux-x64/native/libutils.so"

[<DllImport(UtilsLibPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int foo()
```

But of course this only works on `linux-x64`.

How should I specify the DLL path to follow the `runtimes` folder convention of Nuget packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a C# library depend on an unmanaged DLL whose name will only be provided later in the final application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167802/how-can-a-c-sharp-library-depend-on-an-unmanaged-dll-whose-name-will-only-be-pro)

Comment: @shingo I know from the platform which can be known during compilation phase so different question.

Comment: There's a .NET wrapper for Tesseract (OCR) that appears to solve this with [custom code](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/blob/b6a69bfbb1c61aba63f3c6c201d6ff784557960b/src/Tesseract/Internal/InteropDotNet/LibraryLoader.cs#L32). I don't know how it works, but you might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question. Nor do I have a complete answer, but this can possibly help you on the way to a solution.

The `UtilsLibPath` needs to be a literal string in order to be used with the DllImport (or at least that's what I have experienced so far), so you should declare it as such. It also needs to have different values depending on the platform.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know what the platform identifiers that I have used here are actually named, or if they even exist somewhere.

```
let [<Literal>] UtilsLibPath =
#if LinuxX64
    @"runtimes/linux-x64/native/libutils.so"
#endif
#if WinX64
    @"runtimes/win-x64/native/libutils.dll"
#endif
#if Whatever
    @"runtimes/whatever/native/libutils.dylib"
#endif

[<DllImport(UtilsLibPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int foo()
```

If we can't figure out what the platform identifiers are, so this answer can be updated, then the FSharp.Data.LiteralProviders type provider can possibly be used for a workaround. Maybe also other libraries have them defined, like the much used FSharpPlus.

UPDATE:

I found some more information about how this can be resolved.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cross-platform

My guess is that it can also work in F#

Comment: I added some more info. The context is making a Nuget package.